# Querying polygon data imported from Google BigQuery GIS within R

Tags: r, geojson, sql, google-cloud

I have a geography data type column that each row is a polygons (representing South Africa suburbs) which I have to extract from a BigQuery database into R and from there plot these in an R Shiny app (or use for other analysis).

Unfortunately, I keep running into this error:

> Downloading 77,850 rows in 8 pages. Error in
>   bq_parse_files(schema_path, page_paths, n = page_info$n_rows,  :
>   Unknown type GEOGRAPHY

I have tried various options such as:

```
query <- "SELECT *, ST_ASTEXT(ST_GEOFROMTEXT(wkt)) AS Geometry FROM od_matrix.cartographic_partitions"
tb <- bq_project_query("PROJECT_HARM", query)
data <- bq_table_download(tb) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(wkt = "Geometry")
```

and

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT *, ST_ASTEXT(wkt) AS Geometry FROM `PROJECT_HARM-prod.geography_data` LIMIT 10")
```

I keep having the same errors.

Here are some of the sources, I have tried:

- https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/pull/376
- https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/issues/313
- [Manipulating polygon data imported from Google BigQuery GIS within R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324863/manipulating-polygon-data-imported-from-google-bigquery-gis-within-r)
  [image]

Comment: How do you have "polygon shapefiles" in a BigQuery database? What have shapefiles got to do with it? Do you mean you have a column in your table of the GEOGRAPHY class? Is that column called `wkt`? Can you screenshot something to show us what you can see?

Comment: Hi @Spacedman, I am sorry that I wasn't clear enough. Yes, I mean that I have a table of the Geography data type which is called wit. I took a snapshot of it and attached it to the question I sent to this group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like R package does not understand and fails when it sees `Geography` type.

`SELECT *, ST_ASTEXT(wkt) AS Geometry ...` is good path, but you also need to exclude all Geography columns from query, use

`SELECT * EXCEPT(wkt), ST_ASTEXT(wkt) AS Geometry ...`

Make sure to list all `Geography` typed columns in `EXCEPT` clause.

You might also consider if using `ST_AsGeoJSON` function is more appropriate for your use case than `ST_AsText`. BigQuery uses spherical geography type, and the WKT it produces uses great-circle edges. `ST_AsGeoJSON` converts the shape to planar map, which might be more appropriate depending on application.

Comment: The ST_ASTEXT function worked. I will try to do the same for ST_ASGEOJSON function.